# Настройка локального хоста

Tags: node.js, express, browsersync

Подскажите пожалуйста, я только учусь в Web разработке, работаю в WebStorm, у меня есть BrowserSync который создает локальный хост и watcher -

```js
 gulp.task('server', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            port: 3000,
            baseDir: "build",
            notify: true
        }
    });

    gulp.watch('build/**/*').on('change', browserSync.reload);
});
```

И я сейчас не могу установить от express прослушку для роутеров, так как жалуется что порт уже занят -

```js
   async function start_server(){

    const url = 'mongodb+srv://************************';
    await mongoose.connect(url,{
        useNewUrlParser: true}
        )
    app.listen('3000');

};
```

Может я конечно не правильно все изложил, извиняюсь... но как-то так. Подскажите пожалуйста, если тут что-то можно подсказать...))

Comment: посмотрите, чем занят; например (в linux), `lsof -Pi`

Comment: Не совсем понял. я на windows 10

Comment: ну, у вас, наверно, есть какой-то способ смотреть чем порты заняты

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте запустить BrowserSync без порта

```js
browserSync.init({
  server: {
    baseDir: "build",
    notify: true
  }
});
```

Либо задайте другой порт:

```js
browserSync.init({
  port: 3131,
  ui: { port: 3232 },
  server: {
    baseDir: "build",
    notify: true
  }
});
```

Comment: Не, не помогло....((

Comment: Тогда пробуйте использовать другой порт, например `app.listen(3232);`. У вас возможно запущен какой-то процесс, который уже занял порт.

Comment: Тогда я не смогу получать запросы с порта browserSync (3000).

Comment: Не знаю что вы пытаетесь сделать, но два приложения работать на одном порту не могут. У вас какое-то приложение запускается на 3000 порту `app.listen(3000)` в добавок вы запускаете `BrowserSync` на 3000 порту. Соответственно они конфликтуют. Вы явно что-то делаете не то.

Comment: Да, я вас понял... Спасибо!